# Error when generate signed APK Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I spent 5 hours trying to build a signed APK android using Android Studio but still got this Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

### My gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile project(':externallibs:libraryMaskLayout')
    compile project(':externallibs:library_gellaryfinal')
    compile project(':externallibs:libraryColorPickrBest')
    compile project(':externallibs:lib_TwoWayGrid')

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

### My proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in D:\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-keep class com.myapp.xxx.yyy.** {
 *;
}
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-keep class com.myapp.xxx.yyy.bost.** {
 *;
}
-keep class com.myapp.xxx.yyy.edit.** {
 *;
}
-keep class com.myapp.xxx.yyy.gellery_action.** {
 *;
}
-keep class com.myapp.xxx.yyy.prefrence.** {
 *;
}
-keep class com.myapp.xxx.yyy.new_sticker.** {
 *;
}

-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize

-dontnote com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean
-dontnote com.google.android.gms.internal.zzry
-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.**


-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** {
   public *;
}

-dontnote afzkl.development.colorpickerview.**
-dontnote cn.finalteam.galleryfinal.**
-dontnote com.davemorrissey.labs.**
-dontnote com.jess.ui.**
-dontnote com.squareip.picasso.**
-dontnote jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.**
-keep class cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation {
    public <init>(...);
 }
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

### Thelog file

http://wmdemos.com/log/log.txt

Thanks.

Comment: already try update your tools & sdk ?

Comment: have you clean your gradle? invalidate cache and restart AS.. Please check your gradle build version. it must be match. If not working, please check your library docs on how to proguard your dependencies..

Comment: use `-dontwarn` for all the classes which are unresolved in the log. e.g. `-dontwarn com.pkg.util.MyUtilClass` or `-dontwarn com.pkg.util.**` at the bottom of proguard file.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't require `minify` enabled in your App then you can make it false.

Just change:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

to

```
minifyEnabled false
```

then it will generate signed apk.